# Monthly reputation counts tab on Users page is wrong

Tags: bug, user-interface

On the user page, if you click on the [Month](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) tab, the mouseover says "2016-08-01 to today" but the reputation counts are too high for that period. They seem instead likely related to the past 30 days or so.

It seems to be the same issue on [math.stackexchange.com/users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month).

Comment: This was posted on meta.SE a few days ago, it might be the same bug: [Something wrong with month user rep -some users show quarterly figures?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281997/something-wrong-with-month-user-rep-some-users-show-quarterly-figures)

Comment: Answer to the linked meta.SO post says that after September 1 it should be back to normal. Perhaps if somebody is willing to check whether this is indeed true, we can consider this solved. (BTW I think that ([meta-tag:reputation]) would be a good tag for this questions, but I can't edit on meta. Adding a tag would also bump the question and improve chances that somebody would volunteer to check whether the bug is still there or whether things already work as expected.)